# C# - How to list Scheduled Tasks for a specific user with the TaskSchedular Class

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I was wondering if someone could help me, I am trying to list Scheduled Tasks from a specific user (Admin) on the local computer using the TaskScheduler Class (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx) I have the following:

```
    // richTextBox6.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, taskNames);
    private void button22_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        string machineName = (@"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName);
        ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(machineName);
        // Get an array of all the task names
        string[] taskNames = st.GetTaskNames();
        foreach (var taskName in taskNames)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(taskName);
        }

        st.Dispose();
    }
```

"@"\"" Specifies that the local machine is the target, but is it possible to add a user to this? (Since it only lists tasks that are in C:\Windows\Tasks when executed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to specify a user name when performing the query (only a machine name), but you can filter the results yourself using the `Creator` property:

```
foreach (string taskName in st.GetTaskNames()) {
    using (Task task = st.OpenTask(taskName)) {
        if (task.Creator == "username") {
            listBox1.Items.Add(taskName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the class is outdated, as it only lists tasks in C:\Windows\Tasks in Windows 7, do you know where tasks for users are stored in Windows 7?

Comment: @Mike, they're in `%SystemRoot%\System32\Tasks` according to [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/61f3900b-6572-4ccf-b33c-1b919044e40f).

Answer (score 2):

This only works for tasks created and configured for Windows 2003, XP, Windows 2000.

If you select for Windows 7, Windows 2008 or Windows Vista, Windows 2008 the jobs don't get stored with a `.job` extension in the `C:\Windows\Tasks` directory. They get stored in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` directory with no file extension and in XML format.

The DLL fails to retrieve those configured for Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows 2008.

Answer (score 0):

i doubt you can do this. windows tasks will be common for all the users please correct me if im wrong. but you can get the created user of the perticuler task or els you will be able to get the execution user of the particuler computer.

but this will be differ when it comes to diffrent OS. such as windows 7 windows xp.

Comment: Task t =  st.OpenTask("TaskNmame")

't.AccountName'  //This will give you the name of the account under which task will run 

't.Creator' //This will give you the name of the created user account